# strange " Strong type mismatch" lint warning in case of the struct have a constructor

Tags: c++, lint, pc-lint

I have Encountered a strange "Warning 639: Strong **type mismatch** for type 'myip' in **binary operation**"

```
//file ip4.h
#include <IPAddress.h>   // which have ::ip::IPAddress

typedef ::ip::IPAddress myip;

myip myiptest;   // lint Warning 639 
::ip::IPAddress ip2;  // No lint warnings
```

The IPAddress.h file contains ::ip::IPAddress as follows

```
namespace ip
{
    struct IPAddress
    {
        IPAddress();
            ...
    };
}
```

i think there is no mismatching here!  the PC-lint manual description for this error:

> Check for strong typing when a value is Joined (i.e., combined) with
>   another type across a binary operator.

So what's wrong?

**update:** after trials it appears that this warning raised only if the struct have a constructor , I think this explains things somehow when i declare an object it returns type `::ip::IPAddress` not `myip`  here is the mismatch. am i right?

Comment: Can you show us some more code where you are actually using the variable `myiptest`? Here's a description of the source of your error -- the `-strong` option for lint -- in detail[http://www.gimpel.com/html/strong.htm].

Comment: @dirkgently In this case it is not used except the line shown above, i checked the manual and i think i didn't violate a strong type rule ( type hierarchy , ...).